# unserialize problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing a problem in unserialize the data from the database table. I'm serialized the data and saved into the table. When i'm retrieving the data i'm not able to get it properly. Below is my code .

```
$miscel = serialize(array($_POST['Prod_Price'],$_POST['Prod_Cond']));
```

I successfully inserted the data into the database. In the database table it looks like

```
s:38:"a:2:{i:0;s:4:"4444";i:1;s:6:"Middle";}
```

How i can retrieve the data properly?

Comment: What's your problem, more specifically? Are you calling unserialize on your string?

Comment: i serialized the data and put into the mysql table. But i don't know how to retrieve . I tried with unserialized, but it's not working.

Comment: Are you talking about how to retrieve data from database?

Comment: Then read the chapter in your PHP book about retrieving from a database. StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly is the problem? You should be able to simply call [`unserialize()`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to retrieve your data in its original form:

```
// assuming your database column 'foo' contains
// s:38:"a:2:{i:0;s:4:"4444";i:1;s:6:"Middle";}
$miscel = unserialize($row['foo']);
print_r($miscel);    
// returns array([0] => 4444, [1] => 'Middle');
```

If the problem lies within the fact that the *data being serialized is not very readable*, you should consider **storing the array keys as well**:

```
$miscel = serialize(array('price' => $_POST['Prod_Price'], 'cond' => $_POST['Prod_Cond']));
```

Comment: i followed the same .. `s:49:"a:2:{s:5:"Price";s:3:"467";s:4:"Cond";s:3:"Old";}";` The data saved in the above format.   `$vets = unserialize($list1->meta_value); $output .= $vets['Price'];` I used this format to get the data .. but it's not returning the price value..

Answer (score 1):

```
$records = array(
            'name'=>'abc', 
            'mobile'=>'1234566789', 
            'address'=>'test', 
            'email'=>'test@test.com');
$records_serialize = serialize($records);

echo "serialize<br/>";
print_r($records_serialize);

echo "<br/><br/>unserialize<br/>";
$records_unserialize = unserialize($records_serialize);
print_r($records_unserialize);
```

Here code to use serialize and unserialize

output

```
serialize
a:4:{s:4:"name";s:3:"abc";s:6:"mobile";s:13:"1234566789";s:7:"address";s:4:"test";s:5:"email";s:13:"test@test.com";}

unserialize
Array ( [name] => abc [mobile] => 1234566789[address] => test [email] => test@test.com )
```

Answer (score 0):

http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [unserialize](https://www.php.net/unserialize) function.  This will return every back into an array.

Comment: It's solved . Before inserting into the database i have to use strip_tags!

Comment: @Mayilarun: Not likely, since HTML/XML has _nothing_ to do with the scenario. Maybe you should `mysql_escape_string` to sanitise the serialised input.