# Converting string with keys and values to array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unserialize problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968206/unserialize-problem)

I have a string in the form of:

```
a:16:{i:0;s:3:"696";i:1;s:3:"698";i:2;s:3:"690";}"
```

I am looking at turning this back into array, so that it will be along the lines of:

```
array(16) {
  0 => 696,
  1 => 698,
  2 => 690
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: is it a string or json array?

Comment: It looks like a serialized array, just unserialize it might work? http://www.php.net/unserialize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a serialized PHP string, try

```
$array = unserialize($value);
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

**Update**

The string contains a flaw, as it expects a array of 16 elements, but only 3 given.

Consider:

```
$a = array (
  0 => '696',
  1 => '698',
  2 => '690'
);

$s = serialize($a);
```

will result in:

```
 "a:3:{i:0;s:3:"696";i:1;s:3:"698";i:2;s:3:"690";}"
```

Comment: Generally i would say its correct With the string on top its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function.

```
$array = unserialize($serialized_string);
```